# Unable to make selected text bold/underlined on clicking on tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have some contenteditable paragraphs and I want to be able to make certain words bold underlined when double-clicked. When I double-click a word, it is selected and a tooltip with 3 options is displayed. However upon clicking the tooltip option, the selection is gone and no change has been made to the text.

The questions are:
1) How to bold the selected text?

(Question 2 is not important or necessary.)
2) How to keep the affected text selected?

Solutions are highly preferred in javascript over jQuery.

The following is the code:

```js
var allpara = document.querySelectorAll('p');
[].forEach.call(allpara, function(para) {
  para.addEventListener('click', showTooltip, false);
});

var tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');

function showTooltip(e) {
  tooltip.style.display = 'block';
}

var tooltipOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip-option');
[].forEach.call(tooltipOptions, function(options) {
  options.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.id);
    document.execCommand('bold');
  }, false);
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
#tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 120px;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  top: 10px;
  right: 150px;
}
.tooltip-option {
  width: 35px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="notepad">
    <p class="notepad-paragraph" contenteditable="true">This is my text-ed</p>
    <p class="notepad-paragraph" contenteditable="true">itor. This is what I have</p>
    <p class="notepad-paragraph" contenteditable="true">built till no</p>
    <p class="notepad-paragraph" contenteditable="true">w. Now I am building it fur</p>
    <p class="notepad-paragraph" contenteditable="true">ther. This is fun.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tooltip">
    <span id="tooltip-bold" class="tooltip-option">B</span>
    <span id="tooltip-und" class="tooltip-option">U</span>
    <span id="tooltip-red" class="tooltip-option">R</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you change the `<span>`'s in your 'tooltip' to `<button>` your solution is already working!

as long as your editor style buttons are input type elements, the selected text stays selected.

changed your snippet anyway - the id's now already contain the needed commands for execCmd - so that underline and italic also works.
in the js part you just have to change the execCMD line to: `document.execCommand(this.id);`

```js
var allpara = document.querySelectorAll('p');
[].forEach.call(allpara, function(para) {
  para.addEventListener('click', showTooltip, false);
});

var tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');

function showTooltip(e) {
  tooltip.style.display = 'block';
}

var tooltipOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip-option');
[].forEach.call(tooltipOptions, function(options) {
  options.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.id);
    document.execCommand(this.id);
  }, false);
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
#tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 120px;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  top: 10px;
  right: 150px;
}
.tooltip-option {
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="notepad">
    <p class="notepad-paragraph" contenteditable="true">This is my text-ed</p>
    <p class="notepad-paragraph" contenteditable="true">itor. This is what I have</p>
    <p class="notepad-paragraph" contenteditable="true">built till no</p>
    <p class="notepad-paragraph" contenteditable="true">w. Now I am building it fur</p>
    <p class="notepad-paragraph" contenteditable="true">ther. This is fun.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tooltip">
    <button id="bold" class="tooltip-option">bold</button>
    <button id="underline" class="tooltip-option">underline</button>
    <button id="italic" class="tooltip-option">italic</button>
    <button id="undo" class="tooltip-option">undo</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript change selected text

Interesting problem. We will have to convert the selected text to span elements, or else we cant style the text we select.

Sooo after a couple of hours, i got to this buggy code XD

Currently the bold feature is hard coded....

Selection across multiple lines does not work.

Selection in both directions do work, but not across multiple lines.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  //Function for setting togglable buttons
  var buttons = document.getElementById("tools");
  var bold = false;
  var underline = false;

  buttons.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    elem = e.target;
    if (elem.dataset.active == "active") {
      elem.dataset.active = "";
      switchTool(elem, false);
    } else {
      elem.setAttribute("data-active", "active");
      switchTool(elem, true);
    }


  });
  //Function for chaning what tool we are using.
  function switchTool(element, bool) {
    if (element.id == "bold") {
      bold = bool;
    } else if (element.id == "underline") {
      underline = bool;
    }
    console.log(element.id + " " + bool.toString());
  }

  function replace(s, start, end, replace) {
    return s.substr(0, start) + replace + s.substr(end, s.length);
  }

  function selectText(e) {
    var elem = e.target;

    if (window.getSelection) {
      var selObject = window.getSelection();

      var anchorOffset = selObject.anchorOffset;
      var focusOffset = selObject.focusOffset;
      var elemHtml = elem.innerHTML;

      var selectText = '<span class="bold">' + selObject.toString() + "</span>";
      if (anchorOffset > focusOffset) {
        elem.innerHTML = replace(elemHtml, focusOffset, anchorOffset, selectText);
      } else {
        elem.innerHTML = replace(elemHtml, anchorOffset, focusOffset, selectText);
      }

    }
  }


  document.getElementById("Select-Text").addEventListener("mouseup", selectText);


});
```

```css
.butt {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px 0px gray;
  margin-left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.butt[data-active="active"] {
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px black;
}
```

```html
<pre id="Select-Text">This is a lot of text 
  Lorem ipsum dolar si amet Lorem ipsum dolar si 
  amet Lorem ipsum dolar si amet Lorem ipsum dolar
  si amet Lorem ipsum dolar si amet Lorem ipsum
  dolar si amet Lorem ipsum dolar si
  amet Lorem ipsum dolar si amet 
  Lorem ipsum dolar si
  amet Lorem ipsum 
  dolar si amet</pre>
<h3>Togglable tools:</h3>
<div id="tools">
  <button class="butt" id="bold">Bold</button>
  <!--button class="butt" id="underline">Underline</button-->
</div>
```